# Requiring multiple files for a worker in cljs

Tags: import, clojurescript, web-worker

Currently I am trying to use the cljs library [servant](https://github.com/MarcoPolo/servant). I can only require one file like in this excerpt:

```
(def worker-script "/main.js") ;; This is whatever the name of the compiled javascript will be
```

My main.js looks like:

```
var CLOSURE_UNCOMPILED_DEFINES = null;
if(typeof goog == "undefined") document.write('<script src="js/main.out/goog/base.js"></script>');
document.write('<script src="js/main.out/cljs_deps.js"></script>');
document.write('<script>if (typeof goog != "undefined") { goog.require("boot.cljs.main8234"); } else { console.warn("ClojureScript could not load :main, did you forget to specify :asset-path?"); };</script>');
```

This causes the error that document is not defined, because It is being called from a worker which I presume does not have access to the html doc.
Any way to get around this issue? I had thought making a separate `worker.js` file and filling it with:

```
importScripts('main.out/goog/base.js', 'http://localhost:3000/js/main.out/goog/deps.js', 'main.out/cljs_deps.js');
if (typeof goog != "undefined") { goog.require("../boot.cljs.main8234"); } else { console.warn("ClojureScript could not load :main, did you forget to specify :asset-path?"); };
```

Would work, however I have not had success with this yet. I am using boot to organize my cljs as per [maggimo](https://github.com/magomimmo/modern-cljs/tree/master/doc/second-edition). My js files are stored under the `js` directory. If I have failed to provide any necessary details please say so and I will edit.

Answer (score 0):

As the servant [README](https://github.com/MarcoPolo/servant#caveats) says, in order to make sure that only the non-worker thread runs the browser specific code, you should surround it with the following `if` clause:

```
(if (servant/webworker?)
  (worker/bootstrap) ;; Run the setup code for the web worker
  (set! (.-onload js/window) window-load)  ;; run the browser specific code)
```

Another way is to use a separate build for the worker code. You can see an example for that in the [Butler](https://github.com/federkasten/butler/tree/master/example) library.

Comment: You are suggesting that from within my clojurescript I have code that should  only be executed on the main thread. However my issue is that the compiled javascript itself that I need to require for the workers to share context with writes the paths to the javascript files an the document. Doing what you are suggesting would not solve this. Using butler doesn't really answer this question.

Comment: What level of optimizations are you using for the compilation of your worker js file?

Comment: I am not sure I understand your question. The same boot + adzerk compilation is used for both the worker file and the main file as they are one and the same. I have since decided to try using a more basic approach to clojurescript compilation to learn how it works. Next I can add in features till I see where and why the writing to document is added. However for the hypothetical worker.js file I mentioned there would be no unexpected compilation as it is coded directly in js.